# Moq: Storing away current state when method is called

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

assume I have a class with method Run()

```
public void Run(int param);
```

and string property CurrentState

```
public string CurrentState {get; set;}
```

How do I use Moq to store away the `CurrentState` when `Run()` is being called?
so I can check the state in my unit tests

I've been trying with `.Callback` but I am missing a way to reference the object that is holding the `CurrentState` property.  Can I access a property that is not a method parameter of the called method?

Comment: If `CurrentState` is a property of a mocked object you can control it with `SetupGet()` and `SetupSet()`.

Comment: What is your goal? What are you trying to test and how does the tested code look like? Could you add the code of the class under test and the code of your test you have so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple example how you can do that. Assume you have:

```
interface IInterfaceToBeMocked
{
    void Run(int param);        
}

public class Sut
{
    public string CurrentState {get;set;}
    private readonly IInterfaceToBeMocked _dependency;

    public Sut(IInterfaceToBeMocked dependency)
    {
        _dependency = dependency;
    }

    public void MethodToBeTested()
    {
        CurrentState = "aaa";
        _dependency.Run(1);
        CurrentState = "bbb";
    }
}
```

Then in your test you can do something like:

```
//arrange
string currentStateBeforeRun = "";            
Mock<IInterfaceToBeMocked> mock = new Mock<IInterfaceToBeMocked>();            

Sut sut = new Sut(mock.Object);

mock.Setup(m => m.Run(It.IsAny<int>()))
    .Callback<int>(i => currentStateBeforeRun = sut.CurrentState);           

//act
sut.MethodUnderTest();

//assert
Assert.AreEqual("aaa", currentStateBeforeRun);
```

Comment: I want to retrieve the value of CurrentState (which might have been modified by other objects) I dont want to override the property.

Comment: You have SUTClass which is dependent on IInterfaceA for example, and then if you call SUTClass.Run() it will invoke method from IInterfaceA which will in turn provide or change CurrentState?

Comment: no. Im actually not testing the class itself, but another class that uses it. I want to know the current value of CurrentState at the Point in time when Run() is being called.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Is that what you want to archive?